# vb.net Linq select from enumareable

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I have the following LINQ query which will group by a column and add each group to a datatable in a dataset:

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim query = From r In bookedorders Group By key = r.Field(Of Integer)("productgroup") Into Group
For Each grp In query
    Dim x As New DataTable
    x = grp.Group.CopyToDataTable()
    ds.Tables.Add(x)
Next
```

How can I select specific columns from table `bookedorders` in this query before adding them to the DataTable?
I have 18 columns and I just want to show 4 in the resulted `DataTable`.

Comment: You can only create a DataTable via `CopyToDataTable` with an `IEnumerable(Of DataRow)`. If you would select only few columns via an anonymous type, you couldn't create a `DataTable` from it anymore.

Comment: @TimSchmelter what i am doing right now is using datatable.columns.remove in the loop, but i thought why would i add columns if i will remove them! its a stupid solution but i am tired of searching for a solution!

Comment: Ultimately, why are you needing to push this into a datatable? Why not just use classes/anonymous types for your projection? DataTables seem like overkill unless you really need them downline in your code.

Comment: @JimWooley: If he needs to return the tables from the method he cannot use anonymous types and there wouldn't be a great difference to a `List(Of Foo)`.

Comment: @JimWooley i am using a third pary library to print the tables and it requires that i return the tables that i want to print in a dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only create a DataTable via `CopyToDataTable` with an `IEnumerable(Of DataRow)`. If you would select only few columns via an anonymous type, you couldn't create a `DataTable` from it anymore.

So you need to create another DataTable first with the columns you want to select.

For example:

```
Dim table2 = New DataTable()
table2.Columns.Add("Column1")
table2.Columns.Add("Column2")
Dim query = From r In bookedorders 
            Group By key = r.Field(Of Integer)("productgroup") Into Group

Dim ds As New DataSet
For Each grp In query
    Dim tbl = table2.Clone()
    ds.Tables.Add(tbl)
    For Each row As DataRow In grp.Group
        Dim newRow = tbl.Rows.Add()
        newRow.SetField("Column1", row.Field(Of String)("Column1"))
        newRow.SetField("Column2", row.Field(Of String)("Column2"))
    Next
Next
```